# How to connect to Heroku Postgres Databases from outside of Heroku

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I am trying to connect to the Postgres database (hobby-dev) that is associated with my Heroku application using an external client.

I have read through the docs (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-databases-from-outside-of-heroku) and it seems possible, however I am getting the following error when trying to reach the database from my client:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "[redacted].amazonaws.com" ([redacted ip address]) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

From my inexperienced standpoint, it seems like the postgres instance is refusing connections outside of a certain IP range. I did not see a setting in my Heroku dashboard relating to this (e.g. bind-address, or something of the likes).

Comment: It should work fine without any extra configuration, I use it all the time. Double check the URL and credentials from the `DATABASE_URL` configuration item.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked the DATABASE_URL and I am still getting the same error. I have tried two different clients. It is possible this is not available for hobby-dev databases?

Comment: I've used on hobby-dev databases before. I'd be more inclined to blame a firewall or something.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try from another network and will report back.

Comment: I tried to connect from another network and had no issues. Thanks @ceejayoz, it seems you were right about the firewall.